# Как мне описать метод в структуре OUTPUTDATA ,которые принимают параметры diary, List diary и выводит это на экран Main

Tags: c#, структуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подчёркивает showdata и выводит ошибку в том что Diary не содержит определения для showdata,и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения showdata ,принимающий тип диари в качестве первого аргумента (возможно пропущена деректива юзинг или ссылка на сборку )

myList[0].ShowData(myList);

---

github.com/Raccoon24/Console_Diary

Я хочу чтобы метод вызова был отдельно, чтобы логика и интерфейс не смешивались

Comment: Прикрипите Ваш код!

Comment: Нам ничего не мешает в структуре OutputData описать методы, которые параметрами принимают Diary , List<Diary> и выводят их на экран и т.д. Вот так сказал сделать учитель, но я не понимаю каак

Comment: 1) У ывс нв скрине ошибок нет 2) Код вставляйте текстом, а не скринами 2) Комментарии пишите в комментариях, а не новыми ответами

Comment: В таком случае все эти методы надо вызывать так: `OutputData.*Method*(myList[0], myList);` вместо `myList[0].*Method*(myList);`.

Comment: github.com/Raccoon24/Console_Diary

Comment: Весь нужный код пишите в вопрос, ссылок на гитхаб не надо, туда никто не будет смотреть

Comment: Спасибо большое вам ,вы мне помогли

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую подумать ещё раз над структурой ваших классов данных.
Если вы хотите вынести метод `ShowData` в другой класс (лучше использовать класс, если его элементы не используются), тогда:

1. Его надо сделать статическим и публичным.
2. Сделать из него метод расширения, добавив первому параметру ключевое слово `this`.

```
static public List<Diary> ShowData(this Diary Diary, List<Diary> myList) {...}
```

Однако в данной ситуации разумнее переместить этот метод в описание класса Diary, тогда он станет методом объектов класса и ваша строка `myList[0].ShowData(myList);` будет работать.